# Detect Input.GetMouseButtonUp outside a GameObject in Unity?

Tags: unity, c#

How do I detect Input.GetMouseButtonUp outside a specific GameObject's area in Unity? Are there any Unity Assets for this?

[image]

Comment: Your question currently is not clear enough. Try editing it with more info. For instance, it's not clear what you mean by "outside a specific GameObject's area".

Comment: @MAnd question edited

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using Vector3.Distance(...), checking the distance between the mouse click position and the object(s).
For simplicity though, I would suggest using colliders (sized according to your selection area) and casting rays from the mouse position.

```
void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RayHit hit;
        if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            // do what you want
        }
    }
}
```

You can exclude certain object layers by passing an argument to the physics raycast call. Alternatively, just check that the collider you've hit belongs to a relevant object by checking it's tag, layer, name or one of its components.

Excluding certain layers using a layer mask would be my approach.

**Edit:**
Just to be clear, if you're checking that the click wasn't within one of the non-detection areas, you could use a layer mask to detect only these special colliders and then do:

```
if(!Physics.Raycast(ray, 1000, layerMask))
{
    // ok
}
```

Where 1000 is some max distance and the layerMask is used to exclude non-relevant layers.

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LayerMask.html

Comment: I personally wouldn't use layerMasks for a single object. `hit.gameObject.tag` or `hit.gameObject.name` will work as well to determin, if the object was clicked.

Comment: I see what you're saying. As you already suggested, the result will be the same. However, if you end up having a scene with overlapping objects or collision domains, a layer mask would offer superior flexibility for being able to filter out objects as well as a possible speed benefit as the ray can entirely ignore objects not on that layer (Unity specifics not withstanding)

Answer (score 0):

> **Approach one**
>
> If this is a 2D game then I would suggest creating a quad and placing
>   it below the rest of your objects. Then whenever `GetMouseButtonUp` is
>   called fire a RayCast at the quad from the camera. If it hits the quad
>   then you can progress the code. If it is stopped by another collider
>   (i.e. collider defining do not detect here, then stop the code).

This approach I have decided would be worse to implement, I would go for the one below but have kept it in for the sake of completeness.

**Approach two**

Alternatively, for any areas where you do not want to have detection occurring assign them a layer i.e. `NoMouseDetectionLayer` then use the raycast and if it doesn't hit one perform the code.

```
public class GetInputs : Monobehaviour {
     int blockInputMask;
     // Range of the raycast (value not that important)
     public int camRayRange = 200f; 

     void Start(){
         int blockInputMask = LayerMask.GetMask("NoMouseDetectionLayer");
     }

     void Update(){
         if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp()){
              Ray camRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

              RaycastHit floorHit;

              if (!Physics.Raycast(camRay, out floorHit, camRayRange, blockInputMask)) {
                   // If it doesn't hit an object on the layer perform the code.
              }
              else{
                   // It hit the object so don't do anything.
              }
         }
    }
}
```

This has the benefit that it is easy to assign new areas, all you need to do is create a new object with a collider and set its layer as `NoMouseDetectionLayer` which is done in the top right of the inspector.

Comment: Where do I attach this script to?

Comment: Where you call `Input.GetMouseButtonUp` you add the code for the raycast and you change the layer of whatever object you want to stop input to "NoMouseDetectionlayer". Let me edit it so it is a bit clearer

Comment: Added some more code to make it clear how you would add the code to a script. Also noticed that this is pretty much the same answer as the one provided by Jack

Comment: I'm having difficulties with implementing your script. Can you please upload an example project?

Comment: I can do so later but cannot at the moment. The earliest I can promise is this evening but I might not get it done until tomorrow.

Comment: Hello. You don't have to upload an example project! I fixed the problem.

Comment: Oh really? Glad it worked out. What was the problem if you don't mind me asking?